# Modx configuration problem

Tags: package, modx

I've installed Modx on mij webaccount. if i want to install packages i've got errors when installing.

Downloading of the packages is working. When i want to install ik get this error:

Could not transfer package wayfinder-2.3.0-pl.transport.zip to /var/www/vhosts/******/httpdocspackages/.
Could not install package with signature: wayfinder-2.3.0-pl

I tried to create the directory by hand and give it permission 777, this also not working. I think it's a configuration propertie because it's also with other packages.

Answer (score 0):

That directory, /var/www/vhosts/**/httpdocspackages/ seems wrong.

Where did you install MODX? Where is your Core directory?

MODX will try to put packages into your core/packages directory, but something seems to be wrong in travelling to that path.

Comment: I installed Modx in my root folder. Downloading the packages is ok, but installing is going wrong. Do i need to change my .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your reply. My guess from the code is that your core (in config file) or workspaces path (in the db) is wrong somehow. I'm not all that into stack overflow, so if you still have issues please email me (business at firstnamelastname dot nl) or tweet me @mark_hamstra with a link to a MODX forum topic where you posted this again.